# how to send text from textarea in to the HTML code while typing

Tags: jquery

how to send text from textarea in to the HTML code while typing ?
i would like send text from textarea in to the HTML code and then send it to some div, i using this to live prev

```
$("#par01par03text textarea").keyup(function(event) {
    var stt=$(this).val(); 
    $("#par01Text").text(stt);
});
```

sending from here

```
<div class="inputWraper clearfix">
    <input type = "radio" name = "wykladzina" id = "par01par03" value = "" />
    <label id="par01par03Label" for = "par01par03">Inne:</label>
    <p id="par01par03text" class="formP"><textarea></textarea></p>
</div>
```

to here

```
<p id="par01Text"></p>
```

but i would like to send it in to the HTML code too
do help me pls

Comment: its perfect: see http://jsfiddle.net/UVgdy/

Comment: looks okay to me, what's the problem?

Comment: What you understand by [`DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) ?

Comment: by DOM i understand HTML code i need to send text while typing in to HTML

Comment: If it were that simple... 
nope :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Code Working Fine.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="inputWraper clearfix">
        <input type = "radio" name = "wykladzina" id = "par01par03" value = "" />
        <label id="par01par03Label" for = "par01par03">Inne:</label>
        <p id="par01par03text" class="formP"><textarea></textarea></p>
    </div>
    <p id="par01Text"></p>
```

**Script:**

```
$("#par01par03text textarea").keyup(function(event) {
    var stt=$(this).val(); 
    $("#par01Text").text(stt);
});
```

Comment: ok, mayby I ask the wrong question, i mean that when i writing in textarea  i want to send text <textarea> HERE </textarea> live while typing, now when i typing <textarea> HERE NOTHING HAPPENS </textarea>

Comment: @gidzior, What do you need exactly!, if you <textarea>write something<b/textarea> live in textarea it's reflecting in `<p id="par01Text"></p>`. (other than that you need any thing!)